# Computed property not refreshed for selected rows in Vuetify Data Table

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have an strange behaviour when I try to detect changes in selected rows for v-data-table (vuetify).

Here is a example code:

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    v-model="selected"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    item-key="name"
    show-select
  >
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        selected: [],
        headers: [
          { text: 'Dessert (100g serving)', value: 'name' },
          { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        ],
        desserts: [
          { name: 'Frozen Yogurt', calories: 159 },
          { name: 'Ice cream sandwich', calories: 237 },
          { name: 'Eclair', calories: 262 },
        ],
      }
    },
    watch: {
      selected: function(newSelected, oldSelected) {
        console.log("watch", this.selected.length);
      }
    },
    computed: {
      selectedSize() {
        console.log("computed", this.selected.length);
        return this.selected.length;
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

When I select a row in the table then console shows:

```
watch 1
```

But no shows "computed 1". Why no prints the computed property?

Comment: Where are you using `selectedSize` ??

Comment: please explain further